# Reach and font-awesome

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to use font-awesome from React. I ahve managed to get the example from https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react working with the stroopwafel icon. It is nice and all but maybe not so useful. Now I want to include a more useful icon: [the exclamation mark](https://fontawesome.com/icons/exclamation-triangle?style=solid). However, there seems to be something going on with the naming standard here because when I try:

```
import { fa-exclamation-triangle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

I get: `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ,`

and when I try to remove those nasty `-`

```
import { faexclamationtriangle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

I get `'@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' does not contain an export named 'faexclamationtriangle'.`

So, how do I know what the icons are called?

Comment: Try to use lowerCamelCase format, ```faExclamationTriangle```

Comment: Seems to have worked, but what do I call it then in the next step when I am going to use it?

Comment: You should call it with the same name as you imported it, in this case, ```faExclamationTriangle``` if you carefully read the docs you linked is exactly what they do.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the trick:

```
import { faExclamationTriangle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

camelCase and no pesking `-`.

Next when you use it you should not have the fa, not camelCase and oh what about that second `-`? Go ahead and keep that one!

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="exclamation-triangle"/>
```

Confusing? Yea I sure think so...